# CoreMotion Basic

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-motion

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let manager = CMMotionManager()
        if manager.accelerometerAvailable {
            println("accelerometerAvailable = true")
            manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01
            manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

                println("inside")
                println(data)
                println("x: \(data.acceleration.x)")
                println("y: \(data.acceleration.y)")
                println("z: \(data.acceleration.z)")
                self?.label.text = "Kashif"
                self?.label.text = String(format: "%.2f", data.acceleration.x)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already linked CoreMotion framework. My console output is only

> accelerometerAvailable = true

I am not getting updated label or any of the other console output. What am I missing?

Comment: Straight from Apple's documentation: *Because the processed events might arrive at a high rate, using the main operation queue is not recommended.*

Comment: changed to let queue = NSOperationQueue() but still same

Comment: Did you start your new queue?

Comment: @IanMacDonald is right about not using the main queue, but it still works to do so. The worry is that on the main queue the UI responsiveness could suffer due to handling the high volume of motion data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CMMotionManager` instance is scoped to the `viewDidLoad` method, so it's being deallocated after the method finishes. Thus there's nothing that can send updates to your queue. You want to create the `CMMotionManager` as a view controller property, or of your app delegate if you'll need it across multiple VCs (since you should only be creating one app-wide).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // move the manager out here
    let manager = CMMotionManager()

    // everything else should work fine
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if manager.accelerometerAvailable {
            println("accelerometerAvailable = true")
            manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01
            manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

                println("inside")
                println(data)
                println("x: \(data.acceleration.x)")
                println("y: \(data.acceleration.y)")
                println("z: \(data.acceleration.z)")
                self?.label.text = "Kashif"
                self?.label.text = String(format: "%.2f", data.acceleration.x)
            }
        }
    }
}
```